# как мне испозовать код из useEffect в redux редюсер и можно ли в в redux использовать итерации?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

```
  const {Products} = useSelector(state=>state.Data)

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(()=>{
    
    [...Products]?.map((item) => {
      const text = item.name.toLocaleLowerCase()  
      text.slice(0,3)==='rif' && setRifledGun(current=>[...current,item])       
    })

    
  },[Products])
```